# Running an interval function whilst also handling route requests NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a NodeJS application for my server which will act as an API.

The server runs a function which retrieves an RSS feed and processes it into a MongoDB database every X amount of minutes.

The server also handles routes, for example: when the user requests `xyz.com/api/data`, the server requests the RSS data from the MongoDB and sends it back to the user.

My question is about how to handle the function which checks the RSS feed every X amount of minutes. Currently I am using `setInterval(rssCheck, X)`, but I am worried that if the `rssCheck()` is running while a user requests `xyz.com/api/data`, will the user be frozen until `rssCheck()` has finished?

I understand that NodeJS is single threaded so is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: Your `rssCheck` function is not synchronous and taking multiple seconds, is it?

Comment: @Bergi Yes correct

Comment: Then your current solution is fine and will just work. An asynchronous `rssCheck` will only take small amounts of processing time in multiple steps, being idle during the asynchronous parts, which is the time when route handler can run. You've got exactly the same problem when two users make requests at the same time: no two router handler calls can run at once, the second one will have to wait until the first yields the thread (which it does pretty quickly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`node-cron` can be used to set a cron job that call the `rssCheck()` function every x amount of minutes.

```
const cron = require("node-cron");

cron.schedule(
"X * * * *",
  function() {
    log.info("Running a rss check function");
    rssCheck()
  }, {
    timezone: "timezone",//replace with respective time-zone
    scheduled: true,
  }
);
```

To check cron schedule string meaning use [this](https://crontab.guru/#*_*_*_*_*)